# How to use generate_series to output the week startDate and endDate when input is MonYYYY in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Currently I have that the following **ORACLE** code that outputs the startDate and EndDate of weeks of a given MonthYear as an input.

```
WITH t 
     AS (SELECT To_date('Jan2014', 'MonYYYY')                         orig_date, 
                Next_day(To_date('Jan2014', 'MonYYYY') - 7, 'MONDAY') start_day 
         FROM   dual) 
SELECT start_day + ( 7 * ( LEVEL - 1 ) ), 
       start_day + ( 7 * ( LEVEL - 1 ) ) + 6 
FROM   t, 
       dual 
CONNECT BY start_day + ( 7 * ( LEVEL - 1 ) ) < 
           Add_months(Trunc(orig_date, 'MM'), 1);
```

**The desired o/p should be when input is Jan2014 is**

```
30 Dec 2013 to 05 Jan 2014,
06 Jan 2014 to 12 Jan 2014,
13 Jan 2014 to 19 Jan 2014,
20 Jan 2014 to 26 Jan 2014,
27 Jan 2014 to 02 Feb 2014
```

**How can I use the PostgreSQL generate_series or similar postgreSQL  code to output the desired startDate and EndDate in above format  ??**

Comment: I am confused.  The above code does not work in Postgres, because it is Oracle code.  It should be returning an error in Postgres (the one I get is that `by` is in the wrong place).  So, is the problem that *Oracle* is not returning the right result?  Is the problem that you cannot write this code in Postgres?  Or, do have a particular result not related to the query in the question?  No one has attempted to answer the question yet, so you have a lot of flexibility in fixing it.

Comment: yes you have got it right . Apologies Im not able to write a code in postGreSQL , The above code is Oracle code. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT to_char(d,   'DD Mon YYYY" to "')
    || to_char(d+6, 'DD Mon YYYY') AS week
FROM  (
  SELECT generate_series(d1
                        ,d1 + interval '4 weeks'
                        ,interval '1 week')::date AS d
  FROM  (SELECT date_trunc('week', to_date('Jan2014', 'MonYYYY')) AS d1) sub1
  ) sub2
```

Output as requested.

[-> SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/1249)

Comment: Thank you Erwin for your time and answer

Answer (score 1):

The following query generates the same output as Oracle:

```
select cast('2013-12-30' as date) + n*7 as startdate,
       cast('2013-12-30' as date) + n*7+6 as enddate
from generate_series(0, 4) n;
```

EDIT:

Here is another method:

```
select prevMon + interval '1' day * n*7 as startdate,
       prevMon + interval '1' day * (n*7+6) as enddate
from (select cast(const.yyyymm||'-01' as date) - interval '1' day * (extract(isodow from cast(const.yyyymm||'-01' as date))) as prevMon
      from (select cast('2013-01' as varchar(255)) as yyyymm) const
     ) t cross join
     generate_series(0, 4) n;
```

Note it changes the expression for year and month to YYYYMM.

Comment: Thank you , my question is my input is Jan2014 and in above case its YYYY-MM-DD how can I pass only MMYYY and get the desired o/p ?